# VB.NET equivalent to java.util.TreeSet

Tags: treeset

Is there a VB.NET equivalent to java.util.TreeSet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of TreeSet in Java to C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827913/equivalent-of-treeset-in-java-to-c-net)

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, the .NET FCL does not include tree-bases data structures/collections. You can implement your own though. See [here for a C# example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(VS.80).aspx) (easy enough to convert to VB.NET)

The [C5 Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) is a well-regarded project that:

> ... provides the
>   following data structures, described
>   by C# classes: array list, doubly
>   linked list, hash-indexed array list,
>   hash-indexed linked list, hash set,
>   hash bag (multiset), sorted array,
>   wrapped array, tree set, tree bag
>   (multiset), stack, double-ended queue,
>   circular queue, priority queue
>   (interval heap), hash dictionary, and
>   tree dictionary.

C5 is also C#-based but it does come as a DLL so you wouldn't even have to worry about the language. Just reference it in your solution and off you go.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll find is the [SortedSet(T) class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in, but you could use the [`TreeSet<T>`](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet_1.htm) implementation from the [C5 library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/). This sounds as though it's roughly equivalent, although I haven't used it myself.