# Equivalent of TreeSet in Java to C#.net

Tags: c#, java, collections, generics

I have Java code containing a `TreeSet`. I want to convert the code to C#.

Which equivalent collection can I use?
If there is none please suggest alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516517/vb-net-equivalent-to-java-util-treeset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no treeset in C#.

There was similar question asked in msdn, check that may be useful.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/823c46ca-4a60-4429-a606-e76c3195d4cc/

Answer (score 9):

That would be [System.Collections.Generic.`SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

It does have the methods and complexity guarantees that one would expect from a balanced tree-backed data structure. You can find maximum, minimum, iterate through all elements in order, everything.

See [Add to SortedSet<T> and its complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533007/add-to-sortedsett-and-its-complexity) for more on that.